# В битриксе у не авторизованного пользователя не работает javascript

Tags: javascript, битрикс

В битриксе у не авторизованного пользователя не работает javascript. На карте при нажатии на город должно выходить всплывающее окно, у авторизованных пользователей, все работает, вот у не авторизованных не открывается окно. с чем это связано? Я заворачивал отдельно скрипт и отдельно в шаблон хедера прописывал, но не помогает.

Эту часть Chrome показывает как ошибку `.create("RecallPopup", null,`

```
function openRecallPopup()
{
   var authPopup = BX.PopupWindowUser.create("RecallPopup", null, {
         autoHide: true,
         offsetLeft: 0,
         offsetTop: 0,
         overlay : true,
         draggable: {restrict:true},
         closeByEsc: true,
         closeIcon: { right : "12px", top : "10px"},
         content: '<div style="width:400px;height:400px; text-align: center;"><span style="position:absolute;left:50%; top:50%"><img src="/bitrix/templates/eshop_adapt_yellow/img/wait.gif"/></span></div>',
            events: {
               onAfterPopupShow: function()
               {
                     this.setContent(BX("bx_recall_popup_form"));
               }
         }
        });

     authPopup.show();
                }
```

Comment: Текст ошибки приложите, пожалуйста

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined    openRecallPopup @ script.js:4onclick @ test.php:491 текст ошибки

Answer (score 3):

Нужно было в начале подключить ядро битрикса командой )) Всем спасибо!

```
  CJSCore::Init(array("popup"));
```